# How to measure the percent diff between 2 sets

Tags: statistics

For example

```
a = set(1,2,3)
b = set(2,3,4)
```

The diff between a,b is that:

```
-1 # 1 was removed from a
+4 # 4 was added in b
```

So, how would I describe the % difference between `a` and `b`

e.g.

> 1 item was added and 1 item was removed out of a total of 6 items
>   (because len(a)+len(b) == 6) and so 33% difference

Is there a better way to measure % difference?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is it always guaranteed that the sets are equal size?

Comment: No. The sets could be arbitrary size.

Comment: You could get the size of the union/intersection, and get the number of unique elements. Then make a percentage using those.

Comment: Seems like classical [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).